# What is the mathematical intuition behind àl-jàbrà?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology, math-history

The term *algebra* comes from the arabic term [*àl-jàbrà*](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D8%A8%D8%B1) that means *"to force"*, *"to restore"*. Over centuries mathematicians, in east and west, celebrate by this term mathematical disciplines.

> What is the ***mathematical intuition*** behind this term (*"to force"*, *"to restore"*) and modern
> derivatives such as in abstract *algebra* and *algebraic* geometry?

---

*Append found the [following information](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128161838/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52595.html):
In Arabic, al- is the definite article "the." The first noun in the
title is jebr "reunion of broken parts," from the verb jabara "to
reunite, to consolidate." The second noun is from the verb qabala,
with meanings that include "to place in front of, to balance, to
oppose, to set equal." Together the two nouns describe some of the
manipulations so common in algebra: combining like terms, transposing
a term to the opposite side of an equation, setting two quantities
equal, etc. Because the original Arabic title was so long, and because
it was in Arabic, Europeans soon shortened it. The result was algeber
or something phonetically similar, which then took on the meanings of
both nouns and eventually acquired its modern sense...*

Comment: I am confused about what is being asked. Are you asking about the arabic word, or about modern abstract algebra and algebraic geometry, or both, or is there supposed to be some connection between these?

Comment: The question shall be clear as the answers came well, it is about the mathematical intuition behind these terms of *to force* and *to restore* wherever/whenever we apply the term algebra - e.g. algebra, abstract algebra, algebraic geometry... *what/how do we force or restore in the mathematical context?*

Comment: There seems to be a presumption that the literal meaning of the original word has bearing on how it is applied in modern mathematics, which is what confuses me.  Thank you for elaborating.

Comment: What's the particular problem or theorem you want to prove?  We probably could say that algebra helps us to force some theorems, and oftentimes enables us to restore simpler forms.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood the question is not about a theorem. It refers clealry to terminology (tag) and math history (tag) and History and development of mathematics (topic).

Comment: I was thought that Algebra was named afrer an arabic peron (forgot who Al Kwebrbab or something like that ) and slowly it was  changed to Algebra

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> "The word “algebra”—al jebr in Arabic—was first used by Mohammed of
>   Kharizm, who taught mathematics in Baghdad during the ninth century.
>   The word may be roughly translated as “reunion,” and describes his
>   method for collecting the terms of an equation in order to solve it.
>   It is an amusing fact that the word “algebra” was first used in Europe
>   in quite another context. In Spain barbers were called algebristas, or
>   bonesetters (they reunited broken bones), because medieval barbers did
>   bonesetting and bloodletting as a sideline to their usual business.
>   The origin of the word clearly reflects the actual context of algebra
>   at that time, for it was mainly concerned with ways of solving
>   equations. In fact, Omar Khayyam, who is best remembered for his
>   brilliant verses on wine, song, love, and friendship which are
>   collected in the Rubaiyat—but who was also a great
>   mathematician—explicitly defined algebra as the science of solving
>   equations."

(it's from the book - "A Book of Abstact Algebra" by Charles C. Pinter).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: don't mention it :D

Comment: @EliElizirov: His name is Mohammad Al-Kharazmi and he was an Persian person who was teaching Algebra via Arabic language. Also, Omar Khayyam was another Persian one. :-)

Answer (score 8):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra#cite_note-Boyer-229-12) (or rather, its citation of *"The Arabic Hegemony"* by Carl Boyer):

> *The word* ***al-jabr*** *presumably meant something like "restoration" or "completion" and seems to refer to the transposition of subtracted terms to the other side of an equation*.

Other uses of the word *algebra* or its root simply stem from this original use (just like things involving the word *geometry* no longer actually have to be about measuring the earth).